# File Info in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, file-io

I have some files with name like Front and Back in one Folder like random pattern
ABC_IP_F1 ,

MNO_IP_F2 ,

ABC1_IP_F3

MNO2_IP_F4

ABC3_IP_F5

MNO4_IP_F6

ABC5_IP_F7

MNO6_IP_F8

ABC_IP_B1

MNO_IP_B2

ABC1_IP_B3

MNO2_IP_B4

ABC3_IP_B5

MNO4_IP_B6

ABC5_IP_B7

MNO6_IP_B8

I am getting all the file and merge into one tif formate image but my problem is

How to get file like

F1
B1
F2
B2

means front 1 and then Back 1 then fornt 2 then Back 2 like so on

plz help me ?

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is this:

```
Dim OrderedFiles As String() = 
    My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("c:\").OrderBy(Function(fname) MyOrderKey(fname)
                                                  ).ToArray()

Function MyOrderKey(fname as String) as String
    Return fname.Replace("_B", "_Z") 'make B appear after F
End Function
```

It gives you (if path is omitted):

```
ABC1_IP_F3
ABC1_IP_B3
ABC3_IP_F5
ABC3_IP_B5
ABC5_IP_F7
ABC5_IP_B7
ABC_IP_B1
MNO2_IP_F4
MNO2_IP_B4
MNO4_IP_F6
MNO4_IP_B6
MNO6_IP_F8
MNO6_IP_B8
MNO_IP_F2
MNO_IP_B2
```

Comment: Sir, but I want to decide based on F1 and B1 only which is lastly join means Front and back only

Comment: OK, then return only part of the filename from `MyOrderKey()` which is significant for sorting. Examples: `MyOrderKey("MNO6_IP_B6") -> 0006Z`, `MyOrderKey("MNO6_IP_F6") -> 00006F`. This will give you proper sort order (00006F, 00006Z, 00014F, 00014Z, ...)  even in numbers above 9 are possible, e.g. F14, B14.

Comment: while trying to copy your code giving expexted erroe in below the name function...

Comment: are you getting error at `Function(fname)`? This works only in VB.NET 3.5 and higher. If you can, please make your sentences more clear, sometimes I can hadly understand what do you mean.